# Протокол HTTP, помогите. С++ winsock

Tags: c++, http, winsock, requests

Мне нужно отправить POST запрос на сервер и получить ответ. Запрос отправляется и приходит ответ Bad request 400... Помогите составить правильно запрос.
Вот часть кода.

```
int request(char* hostname, char* parameters, string& message){
    WSADATA WsaData;
    WSAStartup(0x0101, &WsaData);
    sockaddr_in       sin;
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1){
        return -100;
    }
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)8080);

    struct hostent * host_addr = gethostbyname(hostname);

    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = *((int*)*host_addr->h_addr_list);

    connect(sock, (const struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    string send_str;
    char *sendbuf = "987";


    SEND_RQ("POST cheak.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    SEND_RQ("Host: www.exemple.com\r\n");
    SEND_RQ("Referer: http://exemple.com/cheak.php\r\n");
    SEND_RQ("User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0\r\n");
    SEND_RQ("Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, */*;q=0.1\r\n");
    SEND_RQ("Content-Length: 310\r\n");
    SEND_RQ("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    SEND_RQ("\r\n");
    SEND_RQ("key=123");



    cout<<"####HEADER####"<<endl;
    char c1[1];
    int l, line_length;
    bool loop = true;
    bool bHeader = false;

    while (loop){
        l = recv(sock, c1, 1, 0);
        if (l<0) loop = false;
        if (c1[0] == '\n'){
            if (line_length == 0) loop = false;
            line_length = 0;
            if (message.find("200") != string::npos)
                bHeader = true;
        }else{
            if (c1[0] != '\r'){
                line_length++;
            }
        }
        cout << c1[0];
        message += c1[0];
    }

    message = "";
    if (bHeader){
        cout << "####BODY####" << endl;
        char p[1024 * 10];
        l = recv(sock, p, 1024 * 10 - 1, 0)
            _DEBUG_PRINT(write(p, l));
        p[l] = '\0';
        message += p;
        cout << message.c_str();
    }else{
        return -102;
    }
    cout << "end";
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    string message;
    int a = request("exemple.com", "", message);
}
```

Comment: А почему не curl, например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Путь должен начинаться со слеша, либо пишите полный URI, т.е.

```
"POST /cheak.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
```

или

```
"POST http://exemple.com/cheak.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
```

А вообще ходите браузером или curl'ом, а потом копируйте оттуда запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо. Отправил запрос на страницу(check.php) в браузере и получил запрос. Кому нужен запрос:

```
SEND_RQ("POST /cheat/check.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
SEND_RQ("Host: exemple.com\r\n");
SEND_RQ("Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
SEND_RQ("Content-Length: 81\r\n");
SEND_RQ("Origin: http://exemple.com\r\n");
SEND_RQ("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36\r\n");

SEND_RQ("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
SEND_RQ("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n");

SEND_RQ("Referer: http://exemple.com/cheat/\r\n");
SEND_RQ("Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\r\n");
SEND_RQ("\r\n");
SEND_RQ("key=123&uu=456\r\n");
```